# GPS service to run in background (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have a requirement where I have to get data via the USB of my android mobile which is connected to a GPS device , the data should be recursively available whenever any application of mine asks for it.
Something like this should work as Location listener.
What can I use in android such that this requirement of getting data any time from this USB connection, to an application is possible.

Comment: It is **too-broad**, provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running application back ground Use service  and set it as  START_STICKY .